# Entity Framework 4.3 Migrations and Medium Trust

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I would like to use the new migration feature of EF, but on my local machine when I simulate a Medium Trust environment adding "trust level=Medium" on the web.config file, I get this security exception:

```
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.GetMethodBody() +24
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext) +1031
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration) +66
   System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +52
   System.Data.Entity.<>c__DisplayClass2`1.<SetInitializerInternal>b__0(DbContext c) +75
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClass8.<PerformDatabaseInitialization>b__6() +19
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +72
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +185
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c) +7
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +118
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +190
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase() +73
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +28
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +57
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +15
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +37
   System.Linq.Queryable.Where(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +63
```

EF Migrations work in Full Trust only?

Comment: What is it exactly you want to know?

Comment: I want to know if migrations can't works in medium trust or I have some problems on my machine.

Comment: Update your question to make this clear and add any information about the exception or error you are getting.

Comment: Is there any chance that you could reupload this patched EF 5.0 dll? Right now there is 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first [EF migrations CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/07/27/code-first-migrations-august-2011-ctp-released.aspx) mentioned the Full trust limitation with note that it can be addressed in future release but no future release mentioned this limitation as fixed so it most probably still exists.

Comment: Does Entity Framework Code First Migrations still require Full Trust on version 4.3 release?

Comment: @iSid: The question was for version 4.3 and release notes for 4.3.1 didn't mentioned this as fixed so I assume yes.

Comment: So if I don't use automatic migration and I generate a migration script locally and execute it on server, then Full Trust wont be required on server. Am I correct in assuming that?

Answer (score 2):

To your consideration:
I've just discovered what was the problem in my case with EF and medium trust environment.

After reading [this article](http://mosesofegypt.net/post/Entity-Framework-minimum-permission-considerations.aspx) and making some code revision I discovered that one of my EF model class aggregates another class that has private properties. It seems that EF tries to load those properties, which is not allowed for it in medium trust environment. Removing this reference from my model class (I copy needed properties instead now) resolved my problem which was resulting in ReflectionPermission exception.

If this won't help, there is another option which some people claim that it helped them.
Add this attribute at the beggining of your model file or in AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly:AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]
```

Read more about [it here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.allowpartiallytrustedcallersattribute.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the following code in `System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DBMigrator` class constructor:

```
if (method != null)
{
    this._hasSeedLogic = method.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray().Length > 2;
}
```

to:

```
if (method != null)
{
    this._hasSeedLogic = true;
}
```

with Reflector and Reflexil plugin. After this hack it will work in Medium trust environment.

If you trust me, you can download the patched dll (EF 5.0 beta 2) from [here](http://iqgame.weblapportal.hu/ef/EntityFramework.dll)